Why does Adsense Management API always return a 403 error
I am trying to get some data using the Adsense Management API. I have created a project, enabled the API and then created a service account and generated keys for it.
I generate a token with the following code
private async getToken() {
        const { google } = require("googleapis");
        const path = Application.resourcesPath(`adsense.json`)
        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
            keyFile: path,
            scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly',
        });
        let res = await auth.getAccessToken()
            .catch((err) => console.log("err...", err));
        return res
    }

and then use this token to send a request using postman to
https://adsense.googleapis.com/v2/accounts/pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx/adclients

I tried both bearer token and oauth2 and always get the following error
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Does the response body contain any additional info?

I will update the question, posting the response

The access token doesnt have access to what ever it is your trying to access

Thank you for your response. I understand that, however I do not understand why, since I followed the instructions and created the project and service account
